# Display CCK field data in cart block

Tags: 6, hooks, ubercart

I use drupal 6 and ubercart 2. I need to pull cck field data from product nodes and display it on cart block along with products that are already in cart

I created a simple custom module using hook_cart_item

```
function instore_cart_item($op, &$item) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
   $node = node_load($item->nid);
   $item->instore = $node->field_instore[0]['value'];
```

And try to display the values using a template file for cart like this

```
print $item['instore']
```

So far I am getting no results. Can anybody help me with the code?

Comment: Did you ever discover a way to do this? I have a very similar need... I need to display a lightbox link on each product above the "Add to Cart" button, and each link needs to be unique to the product page the person is viewing.

Comment: No I did not so far. I would be happy if you can came up with some solution.